# Excel Add-In running on Windows "fails to fetch" when attempting to communicate with a local https process

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I want to preface this issue by stating that we have successfully gotten our add-in to work with this communication scheme on Mac.

What we are doing is that we have a local HTTPS process (running on the same host that Excel is running on), and we are attempting to communicate with said process utilizing the fetch API.

```
+-------------+     +-------+--TASKPANE--+
| lightweight |     | Excel |            |
| HTTPS       |<---------------- fetch() |
| process     |     |       |            |
+-------------+     +-------+------------+
```

As you may have guessed, we jump through a number of hoops in order to make the request work:

- Our process serves up the necessary CORS-headers
- The embedded HTTP server uses a self-signed certificate, but the custom CA is installed into the system's root trust-store (both on Mac/Windows)
- An entry is added to `/etc/hosts` (for Mac) and `C:\system32\windows\drivers\etc\hosts` (for Windows) that resolves `desktop.ourdomain.io` => `127.0.0.1`

On Mac, this is enough for the add-in to be able to communicate with the lightweight process over HTTPS without any complaint.  However, on Windows the embedded browser fails with the message "failed to fetch".  It is worth noting that this communication topology *does* work, however, in a browser on Windows, just **not** in the Task Pane.

As a last resort, I added `desktop.ourdomain.io` to the domain list in the Office Add-In manifest, and then tried to browse to a known-good endpoint at that domain from within the Task Pane.  It said something like "Excel could not connect with the add-in" (I forget the exact error), and showed a "Retry" button, as if it was ignoring the hosts entry.

Perhaps somebody from the Excel/Windows team could weigh in on how we can open up communication between the Task Pane and our process?